# If $\overline{\operatorname{Sp}}(C)=X$ and $C$ is countable, then $X$ is separable.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis

If $\overline{\operatorname{Sp}}(C)=X$ and $C$ is countable, then $X$ is separable.

It seems very obvious intuitive, but how to write a good solid proof? Notice I take the closure of the span (the bar on top is not so clear).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the elements with rational coordinates. Then set of all such elements is a countable set because it is the union of countable sets $P_n:=\{\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ic_i:\alpha_i\in\mathbb{Q},c_i\in C,1\leq i\leq n\}$.

Let $B(x,\epsilon)$ be an arbitrary ball. We can choose $y\in \text{span}(C)$ such that $B(y,r)\subset B(x,\epsilon)$. If $y=\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_ic_i$, then $\|\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_ic_i-\sum_{i=1}^k\beta_ic_i\|\leq\sum_{i=1}^k|(\alpha_i-\beta_i)|\|c_i\|$. Since rationals are dense, we can choose $\beta_i\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k|(\alpha_i-\beta_i)|\|c_i\|<r$.